# OpenMP array indexing in nested loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I'm having an issue trying to parallelize a nested loop using OpenMP - it's just demo code for playing around and getting used to.

```
int* myresults = new int[1000]   
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for 
    for(int z=0; z<=mainCount;z++)
    {
        results[n++] = myfunc(z,0); //compute something


        for(int i=0;i<=secondCount;i+=5)
        {
            results[n++]=myfunc(z,i);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the indexing of my results array. I assume since OpenMP is parallelizing the first for-loop that he is using positions of `results[]` twice or more because `results[n++]` will produce undefined behaviour (as it cannot be assured that n is incremented right), am I correct?

How can I correctly index and store my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is incremented once for `myfunc(z,0)` and `1 + secondCount/5` times for `myfunc(z,i)`. This means that `n` should be `z * (2 + secondCount/5)` at the beginning of each iteration of the outer loop. You should rewrite your code like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(n)
for (int z = 0; z <= mainCount; z++)
{
    n = z * (2 + secondCount/5);

    results[n++] = myfunc(z, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i <= secondCount; i += 5)
        results[n++] = myfunc(z, i);
}
```